# Deliver some parts of website with json?

Tags: joomla-3.x

Is is possible to deliver some website parts over json in Joomla 3.6.2? I want to deliver or share header and footer because there are some projects on subdomains but the header and footer should be the same...

I know how to work with json on K2 component but not with parts of website... is there any default Joomla! option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something similar by writing an AJAX plug-in.
It is quite quick to write joomla ajax plug-ins and you can set the output to json, or raw.  There is good documentation on this at https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface and a handy code example at https://github.com/Joomla-Ajax-Interface/Ajax-Latest-Articles

Another option would be to use something like the JBackend extension, which can output content and other models as json.  I mainly use it for mobile app APIs, but it may work ok for what you're looking at too. For more info about jbackend see...

- http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jbackend
- https://www.selfget.com/documentation/category/7-jbackend-j30.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to generate Html as a JSON output.

You have to implement your own API to generate a header or footer from Joomla as a JSON output.